# How to get customer that made purchase more than 3 times in 7 days using Holistic (SQL)

Tags: sql

| customerid | orderid | createdat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1B3 | vds34rve4-3f | 1/1/2021 |
| AA2B | hvdhkc767-s3d | 1/1/2021 |
| EA986 | bckd33rfvfbvdf | 1/1/2021 |
| A1B3 | jdbjkvshb3rdec | 1/1/2021 |
| SFK3 | bhabsd-bbc83ccs | 2/1/2021 |
| AA2B | hcbadcbsbc7cd | 3/1/2021 |
| A1B3 | hjjac73an83-3fc | 7/1/2021 |
| DEH32 | gdyafjk-24vfd | 7/1/2021 |
| A1B3 | jkhbdj434jcbjke | 7/1/2021 |
| AA2B | jkkcbjq90ksnc | 8/1/2021 |
| AA2B | cjbugd3ahsddka | 8/1/2021 |
| A1B3 | kbcq7w69ufj4t4 | 9/1/2021 |
| SFK3 | bcdubi7wklcna8 | 9/1/2021 |
| EA986 | cbyatea4jwndns | 9/1/2021 |
| A1B3 | biqbdepaljkcl9 | 9/1/2021 |
| SFK3 | nuqya8wownd2ln2 | 9/1/2021 |
| A1B3 | ndkuq2uowmdlqn | 9/1/2021 |

Table name: purchaseTable

Column fields are:-

- customerid
- orderid
- createdat

One customer can appear multiple times if they fulfill the condition (made purchase more than 3 times in 7 days)

Output:

- customerid
- startdate
- enddate
- countOrderid

for example

userid A1B3, made purchase 2 times on 1 January 2021, 2 times on 7 January 2021 and 3 times on 9 January 2021

the output will be

```
A1B3 | 1/1/2021 | 7/1/2021 | 4
A1B3 | 7/1/2021 | 9/1/2021 | 5
```

Comment: Jeopardy can be fun, sometimes. But if you want assistance, also show us the sample table data that will give the specified result

Comment: Hi already edited the question with table example. Sorry I am new in this

Comment: No problem, we are all here to learn!

Comment: can you help with this? Or do you need more info?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Column createdat data type?

Comment: Why no AA2B in the result? One purchase on 3 January, and 2 on 8 Jan, i.e. 3 purchase within less than 7 days.

Comment: mongoDB but query using holistic, using sql. createdat is date

Answer (score 0):

Basically you would need below approach

```
  Select * from (
   Select customerid, sum(case when start_date 
      <=start_date+7 and countorderid>=1 then 1 else 0 end) as 
        final_cnt
   From table group by customerid ) 
   Where final_cnt >=3
```

Other way round by your table structure  the logic would be surrounded by below.

```
 With Cte as (Select customerid, createdate, count(*) as 
           ordercount from 
   purchaseTable group by customerid, createdate order by 
  createdate) 
Select sum(case when createdate<=createdate+7 then 
           ordercount end) from CTE
PIVOT (for cretaedate between createdate and createdate+7)
```